# How can I install ssh on Ubuntu 12 without internet

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-12.04

I need to install ssh offline on a computer which doesn't have the internet. Is there any package to do it or i need prepare one? How can I prepare? OS is Ubuntu 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps:

- Get the "deb" file
- Give the command by pointing offline package file

In order to get offline installation file, follow this command:

```
sudo apt-get –download-only openssh-server
```

[image]

Install it by using “deb” file:

```
sudo dpkg -i /home/yupana/Desktop/ssh.deb
```

[image]

Comment: this will not download dependencies, therefore it will probably ends with an error. see answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/113965/where-to-get-complete-offline-installer-for-openssh-server

Answer (score 0):

From the DVD, I guess. If you don't have one, I don't see another possibility to do it offline.

Comment: I meant the commands but anyway. There is a detailed explanation: http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline Sorry I asked this question to the wrong section of stackoverflow